# R ggplot stacked bars where each bar comes from custom conditions

Tags: r, ggplot2

I can make a ggplot stacked bar graph where the bars are the categories of a variable, and the stack depends on another variable:

```
data(starwars)
ggplot(starwars, aes(x = eye_color, fill = gender)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

But I would like that each bar correspond to a subset of data defined with a custom filter, from any variable

i.e. first column could be the characters from 'Naboo', second, the ones from 'Tatooine', the third select only the human characters. All varibles, stacked with 'fill=gender'

What I need is to study the behaviour of diferent subsets of data related to a characteristic, all in a single graph, to compare

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think since some datapoints might appear more than once you'll have to make the subsets separately, bind them together then plot:

```
library(dplyr)
data(starwars)
bind_rows("Planet=Naboo" = filter(starwars,homeworld=="Naboo"),
          "Planet=Tatooine" = filter(starwars,homeworld=="Tatooine"),
          "Species=Humans" = filter(starwars,species=="Human"),.id="filter") |>

ggplot(aes(x = filter, fill = gender)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Just what i wanted!. Thanks!